# 61 GB root patition full?

Tags: root, 19.04

I have a 61 GB root partition for Ubuntu 19.04 that is full.
Looking at it with Baobab the devices & location panel says: 1.5GB available 61.5 GB Total
Clicking on it, Baobab shows the circle with only 15.2GB used.

1. Why this discrepancy between the two numbers?
2. How could the root be so large? (I clean and autoremove it)
3. Is there a way to compress it?

[image: root partition size]

`df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            7.7G     0  7.7G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.6G  2.2M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p3   58G   56G  447M 100% /
tmpfs           7.8G  335M  7.4G   5% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop1      142M  142M     0 100% /snap/skype/60
/dev/loop2       89M   89M     0 100% /snap/core/6964
/dev/loop3       90M   90M     0 100% /snap/core/6673
/dev/loop4      148M  148M     0 100% /snap/skype/66
/dev/loop5       54M   54M     0 100% /snap/core18/970
/dev/loop6      212M  212M     0 100% /snap/firefox/226
/dev/loop7      152M  152M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/51
/dev/loop8      175M  175M     0 100% /snap/spotify/32
/dev/loop10     125M  125M     0 100% /snap/code/8
/dev/loop0      174M  174M     0 100% /snap/spotify/34
/dev/loop12      54M   54M     0 100% /snap/core18/782
/dev/loop11      90M   90M     0 100% /snap/core/6818
/dev/loop13     145M  145M     0 100% /snap/skype/63
/dev/loop15      54M   54M     0 100% /snap/core18/941
/dev/loop14     212M  212M     0 100% /snap/firefox/216
/dev/loop16      35M   35M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/818
/dev/loop19     181M  181M     0 100% /snap/spotify/35
/dev/loop20     8.2M  8.2M     0 100% /snap/evince/68
/dev/loop22     125M  125M     0 100% /snap/code/9
/dev/loop21      36M   36M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1198
/dev/loop23      88M   88M     0 100% /snap/meshlab-mardy/5
/dev/loop24      35M   35M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1122
/dev/nvme0n1p2  511M  7.7M  504M   2% /boot/efi
/dev/nvme0n1p4  412G  155G  257G  38% /home
tmpfs           1.6G   76K  1.6G   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/loop25     8.2M  8.2M     0 100% /snap/evince/95
/dev/loop26     152M  152M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/55`

`sudo du -hx --max-depth=1 / 2> /dev/null
66M /boot
17M /etc
0   /media
4.6G    /var
17M /bin
805M    /lib
4.0K    /lib64
0   /mnt
1.9G    /opt
39M /root
12M /sbin
80K /snap
0   /srv
29M /tmp
7.1G    /usr
0   /cdrom
0   /.config
15G /`

`sudo du -sh /root/.[A-z]* /root/*
du: cannot access '/root/.[A-z]': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/root/': No such file or directory`

Just copying the end of a very long list here:
`sudo du -ckmax / | sort -nk 1,1 | tee ~/output
137 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
141 /var/lib/snapd/cache/ea230569aca785460ef3c852ba6991a714794797d20db58b83e82c2d9ea7adad43eaeae93269a39302c69c81cd0c5c6e
142 /var/lib/snapd/snaps/skype_60.snap
143 /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/jmods/java.base.jmod
143 /var/cache
145 /var/lib/snapd/snaps/skype_63.snap
148 /var/lib/snapd/snaps/skype_66.snap
151 /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex
152 /var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-3-28-1804_51.snap
152 /var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-3-28-1804_55.snap
154 /usr/lib/gcc
154 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu
155 /usr/lib/python2.7
157 /usr/lib/thunderbird
157 /usr/local
162 /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser
167 /lib/modules/5.0.0-15-generic/kernel/drivers
174 /var/lib/snapd/snaps/spotify_34.snap
175 /var/lib/snapd/snaps/spotify_32.snap
178 /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib
178 /var/lib/apt
178 /var/lib/apt/lists
181 /var/lib/snapd/snaps/spotify_35.snap
193 /usr/share/locale
200 /usr/share/doc/texlive-doc
205 /opt/libreoffice6.0/share
206 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/wine
207 /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/jmods
207 /usr/share/fonts
212 /var/lib/snapd/snaps/firefox_216.snap
212 /var/lib/snapd/snaps/firefox_226.snap
219 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/wine
223 /usr/lib/chromium-browser
232 /lib/modules/5.0.0-15-generic/kernel
235 /opt/libreoffice6.2/share
238 /lib/modules/5.0.0-15-generic
261 /opt/mendeleydesktop/lib/qt
264 /usr/share/icons
284 /opt/mendeleydesktop/lib
286 /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist
288 /usr/share/texlive
318 /lib/modules
350 /opt/mendeleydesktop
357 /opt/libreoffice6.0/program
363 /opt/libreoffice6.2/program
386 /usr/lib/jvm
386 /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
406 /usr/bin
406 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu
411 /usr/share/doc
430 /lib/firmware
554 /var/lib/snapd/cache
566 /opt/libreoffice6.0
621 /opt/libreoffice6.2
667 /usr/share/tesseract-ocr
667 /usr/share/tesseract-ocr/4.00
667 /usr/share/tesseract-ocr/4.00/tessdata
800 /var/log/journal
800 /var/log/journal/8c65d4da432b4013bf2f5e080b2544f4
805 /lib
844 /var/log
1575    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
1887    /opt
2572    /var/lib/snapd/snaps
2947    /usr/share
3128    /var/lib/snapd
3498    /var/lib
3510    /usr/lib
4612    /var
7187    /usr
14667   /
14667   total`

Comment: output of `df -h` ?

Comment: Have you emptied trash? Or used / (root) and root's trash has a lot of data? I prefer this: Shows just /
`sudo du -hx --max-depth=1 / 2> /dev/null`
to also see hidden in /root folder
`sudo du -sh /root/.[A-z]* /root/*` If no files may show error.

Answer (score 1):

Try `sudo du -ckmax / | sort -nk 1,1 | tee ~/output` to figure out what's taking up the space.

Alternatively, you might have some open file handles to deleted files taking up a bunch of space. Try running this to see if anything large is hidden:

```
sudo lsof | grep -i deleted
```

If there some large deleted files with open file handles, kill the process with the file handle to free the space. You can also just reboot to clear it also.

Comment: I have a very (very) long list of files from chromium, that I do not use, marked as deleted
Example:
<code>Web\x20Co 31314 31355 StyleThre       pablanche   60r      REG               0,27      2748         26 /dev/shm/org.chromium.g6olZ9 (deleted)</code>